# How to use post in amcharts dataloader

Tags: jquery, amcharts

My program is using amcharts & dataloader.js. On page load it gives me an error "GET API-Link 404 (Not Found)"
Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code snippet

```
    AmCharts.makeChart("rides", {
        "type": "serial",
        "hideCredits": true,
        "fixedColumnWidth": '10px',
        "dataLoader": {
            "url": "API-URL",
            "data": {
                "api": "API",
            },
            "type": "POST",
            "format": "json",
            "showErrors": true,
            "noStyles": false,
            "async": true
        },
    //code here
});
```

Comment: POST isn't supported in the dataLoader plugin. You're better off using a manual AJAX call

Comment: @xorspark could pls provide any example for the same

Comment: [This was the first result for googling  "amcharts ajax post"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147742/create-amcharts-by-calling-ajax-api-json-response), which is a similar question that was answered several months ago. You can easily adapt it to your needs.

Comment: @xorspark pls check this amcharts code its showing undefined on x axis
https://jsfiddle.net/cwaoj6fy/3/